# How to configure Monorepo to use both apps on Vercel? (with child_process)

Tags: next.js, vercel, monorepo, turborepo

I have a monorepo with the following structure:

```
-apps
--contracts
--web
-packages
```

I need to run the following script from the contracts folder:
npx hardhat verify 0x... 0x... 536472061365408 86400 0

Since it requires the hardhat environment. However, when I run the script through child_process, I get an error. Here's the part of the script where the issue might be occurring. Here, an absolute path is specified:

```
const contractsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../../../../contracts");
  const options = {
    cwd: contractsPath,
    shell: true,
  };
```

Here's the error:

```
Uncaught Exception     {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"spawn /bin/sh ENOENT","code":"ENOENT","errno":-2,"syscall":"spawn /bin/sh","path":"/bin/sh","spawnargs":["-c","npx hardhat verify 0x... 0x... 536472061365408 86400 0"],"stack":["Error: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT","    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)","  at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
```

Can someone suggest how I can correctly specify the path in the monorepo to run the script using child_process?

The problem is that I don't understand how to deploy correctly. Here's my current command:

```
turbo build
```

If I use the following code:

```
const contractsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../../../../contracts");
const options = {
 cwd: contractsPath,
 shell: true,
};
```

Then I get this path:

```
prod: /var/task/apps/contracts
path: …/project/apps/contracts
```

And in the case of production, it doesn't work.

I think the problem is that only the web part is deployed. How can I properly deploy the project in this case?
Or maybe I doing something wrong?

Maybe I need to change my vercel.json?
But I don't know how to combine 2 apps to work together. Here is my draft:

```
{
  "buildCommand": "turbo build",
  "framework": "nextjs",
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/web/(.*)", "dest": "/apps/web/$1" },
    { "src": "/contracts/(.*)", "dest": "/apps/contracts/$1" }
  ]
}
```

P.s. problem with Vercel deployment, on the localhost all works fine